# AWS ElasticSearch Service and DataStream

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

Does AWS ElasticSearch service (OpenDistro) not support [DataStreams](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/data-streams.html)? I was trying to create a data stream today with AWS ElasticSearch service but was unable to do anything. Trying to get the list of data streams just returns

```
{
    "Message": "Your request: '/_data_stream' is not allowed."
}
```

As per X-Pack docs [here](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/x-pack) it states that all elasticsearch versions after `6.3` would have X-Pack by default, and I'm using elasticsearch version `7.10` on AWS ElasticSearch service.

I couldn't find anything in the docs that explicitly states whether this is supported or not. Would be a great help if someone can give more information about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not support, AWS Elasticsearch Service and Elasticsearch have a few differences.

Data streams is a feature only available in the Elasticsearch distributed by Elastic itself, licensed under the Elastic License.

AWS used a fork of the open source version of Elasticsearch, all the features with the label `x-pack` are only available under the Elastic license, some of them are free, some of them are [paid](https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions), but they were not available in the OSS versions, which AWS used.

From version 7.11 Elastic [changed the license](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elastic-license-v2) and now is available under two licenses, Elastic and SSPL, none of them allows AWS to sell Elasticsearch as a service starting from version 7.11.

This led AWS to fork the last version, 7.10.2 in a new project called Opensearch and the AWS Elasticsearch Service will be rebranded as [AWS Opensearch Service](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/introducing-opensearch/).

Comment: Ah, got it. Thanks @leandrojmp

Answer (score 0):

AWS version of ElasticSearch, OpenSearch, now supports data streams.
Checkout [official docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/data-streams.html) here.

To create a data stream, simply create a new index with below configurations,

```
PUT _index_template/logs-template
{
  "index_patterns": [
    "my-data-stream", // This is the DS index pattern. It can contain wildcards.
  ],
  "data_stream": {},  // This tells OpenSearch to create index as DS.
  "priority": 100
}
```

A data stream is a collection of indexes that are created by OpenSearch behind the scenes. You will still query and manage data on the main index `my-data-stream` but internally OpenSearch will create indexes of format `.ds-<name_of_index>-0000001`.

You can also define "policies" on the main index, like rollover policy, or deletion policy, to manage old data, e.g. to re-index data older than 30 days. OpenSearch will then create a new index with name `0000002` after 30 days and apply the policies you specified on the `0000001` dataset.

You can check for all the datastreams defined in your system using,

> GET /_data_stream